# CheckBox spacing is very different on two phones

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having trouble nailing the spacing between checkboxes and the text associated with them.

My google galaxy nexus shows this:

[image: screenshot 1]

My galaxy s2 shows this:

[image: screenshot 2]

My layout is simple:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_content_box"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile_private_wardrobe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/edit_profile_wardrobe"
        style="@style/Theme.CheckBoxHint"
        />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile_send_me_vouchers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/edit_profile_vouchers"
        style="@style/Theme.CheckBoxHint"

        />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/edit_profile_third_party_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit_profile_email" 
        style="@style/Theme.CheckBoxHint"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

As is my style:

```
<style name="Theme.CheckBoxHint">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

The checkboxes are customised by using a selector drawable and setting it using:

```
<style name="Theme.CheckBox" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/check_box</item>
</style>
```

Which then gets used in the main app theme:

```
<item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/Theme.PMBAppTheme.CheckBox</item>
```

I have tried setting padding to 0 on the checkbox but that just makes the text sit over the checkbox itself.

How can I remove the extra spacing around the checkboxes on the galaxy s2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that setting `<item name="android:background">@null</item>` in my `Theme.CheckBoxHint` solves my problem. There must be some transparent drawable being used as a background.

Answer (score -2):

You need to set your margins, not your paddings.
Make sure your Theme.CheckBoxHint margins are 0.

Comment: Setting 0 margins on the checkboxes does nothing.

Comment: timmied, would you please stop guessing at answers? It clutters up Stackoverflow and keeps folks from finding quality answers with accurate information. Thank you!